# I want to make an autorole on discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So i want my discord.js bot to automaticly add a role to a newly joined user but i cant get it to work,
heres some code

```
//autorole
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    console.log('User @' + member.user.tag + ' has joined the server!');
    var role = member.guild.roles.cache.find('name', 'Newbie')
    member.addRole(role);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Discord JS v12 you need to use `GuildMember.roles.add(Role / Snowflake)`.

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    console.log('User @' + member.user.tag + ' has joined the server!');
    var role = member.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "Newbie")
    member.roles.add(role);
});
```